# Index strings by other strings

Tags: c++, string, indexing, tr1, unordered-map

I need to index specific strings with other strings and I can't really find a good way to do so. I tried to use tr1::unordered_map, but I'm having some difficulties using it.
If someone could tell me what is the best way to do that I'd be really grateful :)
I also need to index objects by a number (numbers are not in order so I can't use a vector)

Comment: A  map of some sort is the right approach - what difficulties are you having? If you need to index in two ways, you probably need two containers.

Comment: @Mark what do hats have to do with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html)?

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> foo;
```

Then you can add elements,

```
foo["bar"] = "baz";
cout << foo["bar"] << std::endl;  // baz
```

Comment: Im trying to use this:     
std::map<std::string, std::string> lang;
std::string fMatch(matches[2].first, matches[2].second);
std::string sMatch(matches[6].first, matches[6].second);
lang[fMatch] = sMatch;
       
but I'm getting this error: error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Can you post a minimal test-case in your question, along with the compiler output? That code looks reasonable.

Comment: first header: http://pastebin.com/1M6p55fG, second header: http://pastebin.com/e74mpFwj, code file: http://pastebin.com/rMbyBdbU, output: http://pastebin.com/wy57wMjC

Comment: @mcco: You have two variables named `lang`. One is a member of the class `LocalCacheLoader` and the other is a local variable in function `loadLang`. In your function, the local variable of string type is getting accessed. Since `std::string` doesnt have operator[] which takes a string, you are getting error.

Comment: Wow! I hate when that happens :\ Thanks for the help all :D